# How to scale point size and color at the same time in ggvis?

Tags: r, plot, scale, ggvis

Considering a data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(t = rep(seq(from=as.POSIXct('00:15:00',format='%H:%M:%S'),
                             to=as.POSIXct('24:00:00',format='%H:%M:%S'),by='15 min'),times=2),
                     y = c(rnorm(96,10,10),rnorm(96,40,5)),
                     group = factor(rep(1:2,each=96)),
                     type = factor(rep(1:3,each=64)))
```

Using `ggvis`, I want to generate a point-line plot in which the line is grouped by `group`. The size of points with `type==3` should be 100 while the size of points with`type==1` and `type==2` are all 50. The colour of the points should be `green`, `blue` and `red` corresponding to `type1`,`type2` and `type3`. Here is my `ggvis` code:

```
df <- data.frame(df,id=1:nrow(df))

all_values <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  row <- df[df$id == x$id, ]
  paste0(names(row), ": ", format(row), collapse = "<br />")
}

ggvis(data=df,x=~t,y=~y,stroke=~group) %>% 
  layer_points(fill=~type,size=~type, key:=~id, fillOpacity := 0.5,
               fillOpacity.hover := 0.8,size.hover := 500) %>% 
  scale_nominal("size",domain = c(1,2,3), range = c(50,50,100)) %>%
  scale_nominal("fill",domain = c(1,2,3), range = c('green','blue','red')) %>%
  layer_lines() %>% 
  add_tooltip(all_values,'click') %>%
  add_legend(scales=c("fill","size"), properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 150))) %>%
  set_options(duration = 0) %>% 
  add_axis(type="x",format="%H:%M")
```

I get the error of `Error: length(x) not less than or equal to 2`.
Why this happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: The `range = c(50,50,100)` should be changed to `range = c(50,100)` if you still prefer to use numeric value for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `scale_nominal("size",domain = c(1,2,3), range = c(50,50,100))` should be replaced by `scale_nominal("size",domain = c(1,2,3), range = c('50','50','100'))`.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit for the error is more than 2 values defined for `range`. The definition for `range` suggests : `For numeric values, the range can take the form of a two-element array with minimum and maximum values.`

`For ordinal data, the range may by an array of desired output values, which are mapped to elements in the specified domain`. In this case, value should be defined in character.

This should resolve your error.

Comment: Yes, I tried to understand the sencond sentence many times. But `an array of` made me confused.